# GaussView and iMac

Tags: apple-operating-system

I'm planning to purchase GaussView and install it on iMacs. Apple is known for messing up apps when it makes upgrades. I used GaussView a while ago and have not followed updates on these issues. Are the current GaussView and iMacs (hardware and OS) compatible?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question? Please update us!